# How to filter and get rows based on group by condition having dates as one of the duplicates column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below Pandas dateframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data= [['A','Sensor1','1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM'],['A','Sensor2','1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM'],['A','Sensor7','1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM'],['A','Sensor3','1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM'],['A','Sensor1', '2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM'],['A','Sensor2','2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM'],['A','Sensor7','2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM'],['A','Sensor4','3/12/2023 3:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor7','2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor8','2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor2','2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor5','4/12/2023 4:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor7','6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor8','6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['B','Sensor3','6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['C','Sensor1','6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM'],['C','Sensor2','7/12/2023 5:00:00 AM']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['System','Sensor','SensorTime'])
```

I would like to get the system rows which have the identical sensors getting tripped for the same time. i.e, System A has three sensors 1,2, &7 getting tripped for the same time for the given month.
System B has sensor 7 & 8 getting tripped for the same time for the given month.

The expected output is -

| System | Sensor | SensorTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Sensor1 | 1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM |
| A | Sensor2 | 1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM |
| A | Sensor7 | 1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM |
| A | Sensor1 | 2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM |
| A | Sensor2 | 2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM |
| A | Sensor7 | 2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM |
| B | Sensor7 | 2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM |
| B | Sensor8 | 2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM |
| B | Sensor7 | 6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM |
| B | Sensor8 | 6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM |

At the moment I iterate (iterrows) for each system groupby and get all the sensor & time loaded in the list of lists and then compare and filter out for each systems. Please advice is there a better way to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can drop unduplicated rows in `System` and `Sensor` columns

```
df[df.duplicated(['System', 'Sensor'], keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby().size` to count the pair `(System, SensorTime)`, also `transform` to propagate the sizes to each rows:

```
mask = df.groupby(['System', 'SensorTime'])['Sensor'].transform('size').ge(2)
df[mask]
```

Output (note how the first group has two spaces    in the sample data):

```
   System   Sensor             SensorTime
0       A  Sensor1  1/12/2023  2:00:00 AM
2       A  Sensor7  1/12/2023  2:00:00 AM
3       A  Sensor3  1/12/2023  2:00:00 AM
4       A  Sensor1  2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM
5       A  Sensor2  2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM
6       A  Sensor7  2/12/2023 12:00:00 PM
8       B  Sensor7   2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM
9       B  Sensor8   2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM
10      B  Sensor2   2/12/2023 5:00:00 AM
12      B  Sensor7   6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM
13      B  Sensor8   6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM
14      B  Sensor3   6/12/2023 5:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Quang - The output expected given in the question is different to your output. Please help to check this. thanks.

Comment: @John not that your input is `['A','Sensor2','1/12/2023 2:00:00 AM']` with just **one** space between date and time. Your expected out put is not derived from the sample input.

Comment: Thanks Quang. Yes, My mistake. do you intend to group by ['System','Sensor'] ? since you mentioned ['System','Sensortime'] the expected result is still different. But thanks for all your help and indeed, appreciated and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Groupby clause may be used on **System** and **SensorTime** column.

```
df.groupby(['System','SensorTime'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Convert the SensorTime column to a datetime object
df['SensorTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SensorTime'])

groups = df.groupby(['System', 'Sensor', 'SensorTime']).size()

# Filter the groups where the count of rows is greater than 1
result = groups[groups > 1].reset_index()
```